# How do I uninstall grub in terminal?

Tags: grub2

I have used Boot-Repair in an attempt to fix a problem booting into my Linux OS, with no satisfaction.
I paid for my version, so I get technical support, and I was instructed on how to install an alternative boot loader, however I didn't ask what or how, to do with the current boot loader, so I'm trying to cover my bases here, by getting an answer to this question;
How do I uninstall grub using the terminal in ubuntu?

Comment: You paid for Ubuntu?

Comment: @AndroidDev I think the OP may be talking about [Ubuntu Advantage](https://buy.ubuntu.com/?utm_campaign=Advantage&utm_medium=takeover&utm_source=ubuntuwebsite&_ga=1.191075311.455562613.1481951023).

Comment: *What is working now, what is not working, and what do you want?* - What linux OS  did you try to fix? Ubuntu or some other linux operating system? Boot-Repair will replace the current grub with a new system, if it finds it 'necessary'. If you uninstall grub, your computer will not boot, so you have to install another bootloader, and you should know what you want and need before you remove the existing one.